# Replacing react state of array of objects doesnt work

Tags: reactjs, react-state

I have a application that when is loaded it makes an HTTP call to the backend, it sets the state with the data of the response and renders it. But later, in other part of the application when I make the same HTTP call and replace the state with the new data from the backend, the state doesnt change atleast it doesnt render.

To make the HTTP call and change the state I do it with this method:

```
getTradesFromApi(){
    backendService.getTrades().then(res => {
        let allTradesFromApi = this.state.trades;

        allTradesFromApi.splice(0, allTradesFromApi.length);

        res.data.trades.forEach(trade => {
            allTradesFromApi.push(trade);
        });

        this.setState({trades: allTradesFromApi});
    });
}
```

Here is how I setup the state:

```
constructor(props) {
    this.state = {
         trades: [],
    };

    this.getTradesFromApi(); //This is the method above
}
```

If you need more clarification or other part of the code, feel free to ask me.

I have seen other similar post, but I havent really found a way to implement it. If somebody could help me I would be very grateful!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you never create a new array to force a re-render, you're using the same state value. Try this

```js
getTradesFromApi(){
    backendService.getTrades().then(res => {
        let allTradesFromApi = this.state.trades.slice(); // slice creates a shallow copy

        // not sure the point of this
        // allTradesFromApi.splice(0, allTradesFromApi.length);

        res.data.trades.forEach(trade => {
            allTradesFromApi.push(trade);
        });

        this.setState({trades: allTradesFromApi});
    });
}
```

You can also clean this function up a little using the `concat` method, which returns a fresh array.

```js
getTradesFromApi(){
    backendService.getTrades().then(res => {
        this.setState({trades: this.state.trades.concat(res.data.trades) });
    });
}
```